# PHP / HTML - if user load page without passing a variable redirect user

Tags: php, html, variables

So if i have a profiles page such as `localhost/profile.php?u=user`
How can i redirect the client to an error page if he doesn't specify the "u" such as `localhost/profile.php` without the `?u=` variable?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['u']) || empty($_GET['u'])) header('Location: page-to-reidrect.php');
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this